# Keyboard shortcut to swap programs displayed on principal and secondary screens

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm quite new to it.

I'm using two screens and I was just wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut that allows this kind of swap.

I assume there is a way to set up a custom shortcut that does such a thing but I'm just as new to coding and think this might be beyond my skills.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Up/Right/Bottom</kbd> will move the active window to the monitor left/above/right/below. See "Settings" - "Keyboard", "Keyboard shortcuts" for an impressive list of keyboard shortcuts, that you also can customize.